# Charging an application fee with PayPal multiparty payments Orders API

Tags: paypal

Currently I am using the PayPal multiparty service

1. Merchants given me permission to accept payment on their behalf on their account using (customer/partner-referrals) API
2. Sellers sell tickets through my application and accepting payments through orders API

Now I want to take application fee for my service same as paypal is taking per order
Note: concept is same as Stripe connect, setting application fee in creating paymentintents i.e.https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the partner-referrals API to onboard each merchant,  specify [`PARTNER_FEE`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/partner-referrals/v2/#definition-rest_endpoint_feature) as one of the third_party_details `features` you are asking permission for.

When creating each checkout order, [specify a `platform_fees` object.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/immediate-capture/)

Comment: Thanks Preston PHX that works for me but Partner commission is deducted from order but not credited to application owner account(test account). can you please help me where can i see that amount ? below is order detail

Comment: `Payment details
Gross Amount$111.38 USD
PayPal Fee-$4.38 USD
Partner Commission-$7.00 USD
Net Amount$100.00 USD
Partner NameTest Store`